# Maintain site width when rotating to landscape or using on larger displays

Tags: css, scaling, viewport

I have a mobile site which works well on phones and small tablets in portrait mode.

http://taviationmuseum.appspot.com/

The site functions fine in landscape mode, but due to the nature of the images, the scaling looks undesirable.

Instead, I'd like to roughly maintain the width that the site has in portrait and 'center' the contents with whitespace on either site.

What would be the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

firstly you can re-slice your this image `front-spread.jpg` by maximum resolution right now its with `640*905`so now if we are viewing this on larger screens its going to pixel-late. 
So if you will re-slice with maximum value and set with `media-queries` according to various screen sizes it will automatically adjust according to your requirement..

Comment: This sounds perfect.  I'm new to media-queries, could you provide a few more specifics on how to make this happen?

Comment: hey chambo you can see the link :- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: you can write separate CSS for separate screen resolutions through media-queries.....

Comment: chambo you can also read this article also :- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/a-basic-responsive-grid-plus-handy-css3-media-query-reporter/?search_index=1

Comment: Thanks, I will give these a try.  As a start, I will write new css for screens wider than 720px- that will account for landscape mode on newer smartphones and landscape/portrait mode on most tablets